# Configuration window for list of connections

Tags: c#, user-interface, data-binding, configuration

I'm writing a program that needs a configuration window for a list of connections. I have a ListBox to list the connections, and 8 or so settings for each entry. It seems I should use data bindings somehow to bind the data to something (possibly directly to the built-in settings system somehow?), how should I implement this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are ready to design your program within Microsoft [patterns & practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998572.aspx) guidelines, you can use the predefined [Design-Time Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd139921.aspx). The Enterprise Library configuration tools include a *visual configuration editor*:

> The design-time configuration support includes classes that allow you to change the configuration settings by using the Enterprise Library configuration tools. These classes provide a visual representation of the different configuration settings (such as the image that appears next to the configuration setting), the actions that can be performed based on the current configuration state, and the ability to validate the configuration settings.